# How can I contribute to a contrib module within the context of another active site?

Tags: community-official-site

I am working on a new feature for a contrib module. I have created an issue and followed the new process just put in place for contributing code, as described on [Creating issue forks and merge requests](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/git/using-git-to-contribute-to-drupal/creating-issue-forks-and-merge-requests).

I would like to contribute to that module within the context of the site that is driving this new feature, but I am unsure of how to achieve it and still be able to test the changes introduced in the issue fork.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: The question is not clear in some points. Since you said you opened an issue, I take you would want to add a feature to an existing module hosted on drupal.org. If that is the case, then you aren't developing a module. You are writing the code for a feature, which is then provided to the project maintainers via a patch or an issue fork. The project maintainers would eventually add the feature to the module. Until the project maintainers don't do that, the feature isn't available on the module every user will install from drupal.org.

Comment: "Best" would probably be to provide patches/merge requests to the dev branch of the existing contrib module and then pull the patches into your site, which also would have the latest dev installed. But I don't know if you want to take the risk of running a dev version in production.

Comment: Keep in mind that feature requests for projects hosted on drupal.org can be declined from project maintainers.

Comment: Correct. I am developing a feature for an existing module that the maintainer would need to accept and include in the package.  But the question remains– I have a Drupal module Repo cloned locally that isn't part of my project site, but I would like to develop it within the context of that site as it would provide the other dependencies needed to develop, debug, and test the module.  I realize unit tests can be used for this purpose, though they are not a replacement for real site testing.

Comment: You could simply provide the patches locally, too.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I certainly understand it can be declined and never make it into the project.  All the more reason to get something working with my project that doesn't involve a patch that consists of many files. In this case, the module maintainer is on board with this new feature.

Comment: As developer of Drupal modules, I don't see any problem in having a local clone of 
a module repository, considering that is temporary until the feature is merged into the module hosted on drupal.org. That is the usual workflow used when fixing a bug in a module hosted on drupal.org or in Drupal core. It also used for implementing a new feature for a project hosted on drupal.org.

Comment: If you are worried the project maintainer could not accept the feature request, clone the module and make the changes you want. You could create a project on drupal.org, and you would be able to install it on the client's site using Composer or an archive generated from drupal.org.

Comment: @kiamlaluno – Well, well, duplicate modules. 

Comment: Even better, if you are ready to maintain a module, create one for the feature you want to add. This is indeed possible if the module on drupal.org offers hooks to alter its behavior.

Comment: @leymannx Cough, cough. 

Comment: Yeah, this sounds like a wise solution. If the feature you want to add can be provided from hooks, or plugins or other isolated classes, create your own module on drupal.org to basically act as an add-on to the other contrib module.

Comment: I feel like most of these comments are missing the point of the question. It's not "should I develop a patch, fork a module, or make a new one?" All of those solutions still pose the same question: What is the best development workflow to do this?

Comment: So suppose you have a checkout of a module repository. What is the standard practice for making changes that can be tested within the context of a full Drupal install? Is this checkout sitting in the modules directory of a site which is itself in a separate Git repo? Do most developers use a non-versioned Drupal install for this "host" site during module development? Or is the module sitting outside an install and referred to by symlink or something? Is there an accepted practice for this?

Comment: What does `develop this module within the context of the site that is driving this new feature` **or** `can be tested within the context of a full Drupal install` supposed to mean?

Comment: Do you know of Behat?

Comment: The only way for testing a patch is setting tests for the project for which the patch is created and submitted in a issue. That is something only project maintainers and drupal.org Git administrators can do. Issue forks should also be covered by tests, but I am not sure that is actually done. (The plan is doing that.)

Comment: Are you referring to https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_ups/issues/3183521?

Comment: @leymannx I am not talking about "testing" in the sense of behavioral testing or unit testing. I mean simply writing a line of code and seeing what happens on the site as a result. You need to have the in-development module installed and enabled on a Drupal site to do this. How is this Drupal site typically managed? If a Composer install, then is the module under development omitted from composer.json entirely so that it can be separately checked out from Git?